# How to backup an sqlite database on shared folder with batch file executed as scheduled task?

Tags: batch-file, sqlite

I have a sqlite file that I can access through UNC for backup purposes only.

With `sqlite3` I do the following from my computer in interactive mode.

```
C:\users\username>sqlite3.exe
.cd \\\\MyShare\\subfolder
.open mydatabase.db
.backup mydailybackup.bak
.quit
```

Now, I'm trying to put this into a batch file and configure a scheduled task for daily backup. But only the first line `sqlite3.exe` is being recognized.

I also searched and there are some one liners. But I always get the error: `unrecognized token: "\"`

I also attempted following code in batch file:

```
sqlite3.exe
echo .cd \\\\MyShare\\Subfolder
pause
```

But I had no luck with this approach.

Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is not that I can't schedule the task. I have done this dozens of times with other batch files. I'm just having a problem with sqlite3 commands and the batch file.

Comment: I just edited to match the folder names to make it less confusing. Before commenting and submit as duplicated, perhaps you should read the question more clearly.  I also have not even started scheduling the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sqlite3 \\MyShare\subfolder\mydatabase.db ".backup mydailybackup.bak"
```

It works for me. If you want to backup in shared folder, this works:

```
sqlite3 \\MyShare\subfolder\mydatabase.db ".backup \\\\MyShare\\subfolder\\mydailybackup.bak"
```

Comment: thanks bro. I tried similar things but it was easier than it should have. Thanks for reading my question!!